# I am having some issues with the existing code. I am using Facenet for face recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

In this code it picks a random image from my test folder and predicts the output by giving name of the person matching with accuracy score, but instead of randomly picking image, I want to give my own image path for prediction , please help me out.

**The below code takes all images from local storage and extract faces using mtcnn**

```
# face detection for the 5 Celebrity Faces Dataset
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import savez_compressed
from numpy import asarray
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN

# extract a single face from a given photograph
def extract_face(filename, required_size=(160, 160)):
    # load image from file
    image = Image.open(filename)
    # convert to RGB, if needed
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    # convert to array
    pixels = asarray(image)
    # create the detector, using default weights
    detector = MTCNN()
    # detect faces in the image
    results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
    # extract the bounding box from the first face
    x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']
    # bug fix
    x1, y1 = abs(x1), abs(y1)
    x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
    # extract the face
    face = pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    # resize pixels to the model size
    image = Image.fromarray(face)
    image = image.resize(required_size)
    face_array = asarray(image)
    return face_array

# load images and extract faces for all images in a directory
def load_faces(directory):
    faces = list()
    # enumerate files
    for filename in listdir(directory):
        # path
        path = directory + filename
        # get face
        face = extract_face(path)
        # store
        faces.append(face)
    return faces

# load a dataset that contains one subdir for each class that in turn contains images
def load_dataset(directory):
    X, y = list(), list()
    # enumerate folders, on per class
    for subdir in listdir(directory):
        # path
        path = directory + subdir + '/'
        # skip any files that might be in the dir
        if not isdir(path):
            continue
        # load all faces in the subdirectory
        faces = load_faces(path)
        # create labels
        labels = [subdir for _ in range(len(faces))]
        # summarize progress
        print('>loaded %d examples for class: %s' % (len(faces), subdir))
        # store
        X.extend(faces)
        y.extend(labels)
    return asarray(X), asarray(y)

load train dataset
trainX, trainy = load_dataset('5-celebrity-faces-dataset/train/')
print(trainX.shape, trainy.shape)
# load test dataset
testX, testy = load_dataset('5-celebrity-faces-dataset/val/')
# save arrays to one file in compressed format
savez_compressed('5-celebrity-faces-dataset.npz', trainX, trainy, testX, testy)
```

**The code below calculates face embedding for each face in dataset using facenet**

```
    # calculate a face embedding for each face in the dataset using facenet
from numpy import load
from numpy import expand_dims
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import savez_compressed
from keras.models import load_model

# get the face embedding for one face
def get_embedding(model, face_pixels):
    # scale pixel values
    face_pixels = face_pixels.astype('float32')
    # standardize pixel values across channels (global)
    mean, std = face_pixels.mean(), face_pixels.std()
    face_pixels = (face_pixels - mean) / std
    # transform face into one sample
    samples = expand_dims(face_pixels, axis=0)
    # make prediction to get embedding
    yhat = model.predict(samples)
    return yhat[0]

# load the face dataset
data = load('5-celebrity-faces-dataset.npz')
trainX, trainy, testX, testy = data['arr_0'], data['arr_1'], data['arr_2'], data['arr_3']
print('Loaded: ', trainX.shape, trainy.shape, testX.shape, testy.shape)
# load the facenet model
model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5')
print('Loaded Model')
# convert each face in the train set to an embedding
newTrainX = list()
for face_pixels in trainX:
    embedding = get_embedding(model, face_pixels)
    newTrainX.append(embedding)
newTrainX = asarray(newTrainX)
print(newTrainX.shape)
# convert each face in the test set to an embedding
newTestX = list()
for face_pixels in testX:
    embedding = get_embedding(model, face_pixels)
    newTestX.append(embedding)
newTestX = asarray(newTestX)
print(newTestX.shape)
# save arrays to one file in compressed format
savez_compressed('5-celebrity-faces-embeddings.npz', newTrainX, trainy, newTestX, testy)
```

**The code below is for making a classifier which takes a random image from dataset and make predictions on it**

```
   # develop a classifier for the 5 Celebrity Faces Dataset
from random import choice
from numpy import load
from numpy import expand_dims
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from matplotlib import pyplot
# load faces
data = load('5-celebrity-faces-dataset.npz')
testX_faces = data['arr_2']
# load face embeddings
data = load('5-celebrity-faces-embeddings.npz')
trainX, trainy, testX, testy = data['arr_0'], data['arr_1'], data['arr_2'], data['arr_3']
# normalize input vectors
in_encoder = Normalizer(norm='l2')
trainX = in_encoder.transform(trainX)
testX = in_encoder.transform(testX)
# label encode targets
out_encoder = LabelEncoder()
out_encoder.fit(trainy)
trainy = out_encoder.transform(trainy)
testy = out_encoder.transform(testy)
# fit model
model = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
model.fit(trainX, trainy)
```

The code below, which says test model on a random example from test dataset, So basically what it does, is it takes a random image from my test folder and predicts the output for that. But I don't want a random image to be picked, Instead I want to specify path of image of my choice to make predictions for it

```
# test model on a random example from the test dataset
selection = choice([i for i in range(testX.shape[0])])
random_face_pixels = testX_faces[selection]
random_face_emb = testX[selection]
random_face_class = testy[selection]
random_face_name = out_encoder.inverse_transform([random_face_class])
# prediction for the face
samples = expand_dims(random_face_emb, axis=0)
yhat_class = model.predict(samples)
yhat_prob = model.predict_proba(samples)
# get name
class_index = yhat_class[0]
class_probability = yhat_prob[0,class_index] * 100
predict_names = out_encoder.inverse_transform(yhat_class)
print('Predicted: %s (%.3f)' % (predict_names[0], class_probability))
print('Expected: %s' % random_face_name[0])
# plot for fun
pyplot.imshow(random_face_pixels)
title = '%s (%.3f)' % (predict_names[0], class_probability)
pyplot.title(title)
pyplot.show()
```

Please help me out , how to give my own image path for recognition
please help

Comment: the path is right there: `trainX, trainy = load_dataset('5-celebrity-faces-dataset/train/')`

Comment: The above path is for the dataset 
I want to give an external image path for which I could predict the label

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.